# Delete duplicate rows between worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have two sheets with a basic structure: Sheet(A) and Sheet(B). Sheet(B) is a subset from sheet(A) that needs to be removed from Sheet(A). How can this be done in Excel 2007?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872386/excel-remove-rows-with-same-data/5873507#5873507

Answer (score 0):

Edited the comment's code to work across sheets; this will compare `sheet 1 Column A` to `sheet 2 column A` and remove duplicates from `sheet 1`

```
Sub removematches()
Dim firstcolumn() As Variant
Dim A As Range
Dim B As Range
Dim i As Long, del As Long

'This will set the ranges to look in.  
Set A = Range("A:A")
Set B = Range("Sheet2!A:A")

firstcolumn = A

ReDim Preserve firstcolumn(1 To UBound(firstcolumn), 1 To 2) As Variant
i = 1
del = 0

Do While i <= UBound(firstcolumn)
    firstcolumn(i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(B, firstcolumn(i, 1))
    If firstcolumn(i, 2) > 0 Then
        Range("A1").Offset(i - del - 1, 0).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        del = del + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```